# Command Prompt Help, using dir to list files that start with one letter

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, directory, command

I'm currently in a coding class and have run into a roadblock, I'm pretty sure it's super simple but I just can't find on any forum or other online help. I'm working with Command Prompt on Windows and need to use the DIR command but specifically to only list the files that start with a letter. What would the command for this look like?

Comment: [SS64](https://ss64.com/nt/) is usually very helpful for starters. In this special case especially the [wildcards](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-wildcards.html) sec tion.

Comment: Also I wouldn’t tag powershell if you’re not using it. But as @Stephan mentioned. You’re going to want to look at how to specify wildcard characters

Comment: Please specify "start with one letter". What about `a.txt` (having exactly one letter), `ab.txt` (starting with a letter but may have more chars), `a100.txt` or `a_file.txt` (starting with exactly one letter, second char is not a letter, may have more chars, letters or other)? Which of those should be listed? Do you need the filenames only or the "usual" `dir` output (date/time, size, filename)?

Comment: ... or is it "start with a specific letter"? (Would be my guess, given the circumstances of your question) Then it's easy: `dir n*` lists all files that start with the letter `n` (or `N` - `dir` is case insensitive). See the "Wildcards" link in my first comment for what `*` means.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know `cmd` does not support 'letter' wildcard. But, you can use findstr command to filter unnecessary items using regex-like syntax:

```
dir /a-d /b | findstr /I "^[A-Z].*"
```

Please type `dir /?` and `findstr /?` to see all options.

In PowerShell you can use:

```
dir "[A-Z]*" -File
```